# Sampling scenario with replacement

Tags: probability, sampling

Suppose a population of size $n =n_1 + n_2$ contains $ n_1$ individuals of type 1 and $n_2$ individuals of type 2. If a sample of size k is drawn with replacement from this population, what is the probability it contains k1 individuals of type 1 and $k_2 = k−k_1$ individuals of type 2.

I am struggling to show this is equal to $${k \choose k_1}\frac{n_1^{k_1}n_2^{k_2}}{n^k}$$

Comment: The terms K_1, K_2, individuals, type 1, and type 2 makes the statement a bit annoying to read and think about no? Why not use a,b, balls, red, and blue instead? Maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1:

Sample space(S): No.of  ways we can fill up 'k' spaces using 'n' elements with replacement is given by $(n)^k$, since every space has 'n' options available.

Event(A): Filling up 'k'spaces with exactly '$k_1$'spaces by '$n_1$' elements and '$k_2$'spaces by '$n_2$' elements

This can be done by choosing '$k_1$'spaces from 'k' and fill it up with '$n_1$' elements, the rest of the spaces can be filled by '$n_2$' automatically

= $\binom{k}{k_1}(n_1)^{k_1}(n_2)^{k_2}$

Probability = ${k \choose k_1}\frac{n_1^{k_1}n_2^{k_2}}{n^k}$

Method 2: Using Binomial distribution

Probability of selecting '$n_1$' = $\frac{n_1}{n}$

Probability of selecting '$n_2$' = $\frac{n_2}{n}$

Probability of getting '$n_1$'  $k_1$ times out of $k$ = $\binom{k}{k_1} \left(\frac{n_1}{n}\right)^{k_1}\left(\frac{n_2}{n}\right)^{k_2}$  where $k=k_1+k_2$

Answer (score 0):

This question is about [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

you can re-write the term as

$$\binom{n}{k_1} \left(\frac{K_1}{N}\right)^{k_1}\left(\frac{K_2}{N}\right)^{k_2}$$